# Does the HC-05 bluetooth device support AVRCP commands?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to control the android music player from an Arduino with an HC-05 Bluetooth module. I have successfully paired them in serial mode but have been unable to find any means to connect them with the AVRCP profile. Is there a library that I can load into a sketch to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The HC-05 supports SPP only. In order to get any other BlueTooth profile on there, you would have to create and flash different firmware for the Broadcom BC417143.

Comment: I suspected as much. Could you point me in the right direction to find more information on flashing the chip with new firmware?

Comment: http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/sdk.php -- be prepared to pay for the privilege. Nordic is cheaper.